# SendMessage - strange return values

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

I have an application which uses a three helper threads to read from a database (3 different tables, ~160,000 rows in total), create objects from those rows, then add the objects to one of two lists, depending on what type of object was created. The helper threads add objects to the list through a SendMessage call so that the main thread is the only object adding/removing to/from the list.

The odd thing is that SendMessage doesn't always succeed, I'll frequently get these two errors ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS (183) and ERROR_TRUSTED_DOMAIN_FAILURE (1788). The function that SendMessage calls just adds an object to the list, and this function always returns success (0). There's no creating files (as ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS seems to suggest) and there's no network calls so I'm not sure why I'm getting ERROR_TRUSTED_DOMAIN_FAILURE errors.

Any ideas on what might be causing these errors or any way to debug these errors?

As a note, before it was SendMessage I was using PostMessage and would get lots of ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_QUOTA errors; SendMessage makes the utility work a lot better.

Comment: If I do PostMessage, could I still use GetLastError()? I like the thread-safe array approach, thanks.

Comment: @HansPassant what do you mean by that? The part where it says that i still does processing of "non-queued incoming messages" (is that other `SendMessage()`s?)?

Comment: That only applies if the worker thread created its own window(s) and has a message queue.  Very unlikely to apply here.

Comment: @HansPassant so what am I missing in the docs that says non-system messages aren't thread-safe? Or are we distinguishing between thread-safe and blocks the calling thread from running?

Comment: Non-system messages that are sent to another process cannot contain pointers, as they are not auto-marshaled into the target process's address space. However, non-system messages that are sent within the sender's own process can contain pointers, and should be thread-safe since the sending code is blocked until the receiving window procedure has finished processing the message.

Answer (score 2):

`SendMessage()` returns the result of the message that is sent.  It is up to the message handler to decide what value is actually returned by `SendMessage()` to the sending code.  `GetLastError()` is only meaningful if `SendMessage()` itself fails, and you have to use `SetLastError()` to detect that, eg:

```
SetLastError(0);
LRESULT res = SendMessage(...);
if ((res == 0) && (GetLastError() != 0))
{
    // send failed, for example GetLastError()=ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED if UIPI blocked the message ...
}
else
{
    // send succeeded, res is whatever value the message handler returned ...
}
```

This only works reliably if the target `HWND` is owned by a **different thread** than the one that is calling `SendMessage()`.  `GetLastError()` cannot be influenced across thread boundaries.  Any call to `SetLastError()` within the message handler affects the error code of the `HWND`'s owning thread, not the error code of the sending thread.

However, if the target `HWND` is owned by the **same thread** that is calling `SendMessage()`, and the message handler *happens* to call `SetLastError()` (directly, or indirectly via a failed API call) to set a non-zero error code, and *happens* to return 0 as its result value for `SendMessage()` to return to the sender, then the only way I can think of for the sender to differentiate whether the error code returned by `GetLastError()` was set by `SendMessage()` itself on failure, or set by the message handler, is to use a thread-locale message hook via `SetWindowsHookEx()` to detect whether the message handler was actually called or not (the only condition I can think of for that happening is if the target `HWND` is invalid so `SendMessage()` cannot find its window procedure).

You can use `GetWindowThreadProcessId()` and `GetCurrentThreadId()` to check if the target `HWND` is owned by the calling thread or not.

Comment: But is this reliable? Nothing stops my message from doing the same thing. Or am I misunderstanding what you are trying to convey?